# JTree selection on mouse release

Tags: java, swing, mouse, selection, jtree

I'm using a `JTree` to generate some tab for my application.

Every time I select a node on right panel I load a new page.

I'd like to generate the node selection event on mouse release.

Comment: see Oracle tutorials [Responding to Node Selection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select) and with important details in [How to Write a Tree Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treeselectionlistener.html)

Comment: thanks for the response but the jtree selection listeners generate the event on mouse pressed, not on mouse released as i need.

Comment: *"on mouse released as i need"* The user needs a GUI that behaves in a standard and predictable manner, [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)!

Comment: ehm what i'm doing is not a standard application but a big application in team and the navigation is based on a jtree to make our work more simple.. If i only need a standard way i will not surely disturb the community.. I think everyone like to do all in a standard way but it's not always possible. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it has significant user interface implications, you might look at the approach shown in [*JTree select on mouse release*](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1348063). It replaces all instances of `MouseListener` in the tree with a listener that forwards the desired mouse events to the original.

Comment: i try to implement this method, but when i try to emulate the mousePressed event it will be ignored by method SwingUtilities2.shouldIgnore(MouseEvent, JComponent). I think it check if the event is system generated.